# How can I write with proper alignment in latex?

Tags: latex

I was trying to write a CV on latex. The format looks like the below picture [image: Expected outcome]
I've tried doing that using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\hline
\begin{paragraph}{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}} 
\mbox{}

{Sep 2020 — Present} \hfill{\bf Project Manager, X Consultancy} \hfill 
{Groningen} \\ 
{\mbox{}} \hfill {Have gone through certain projects. Lorem ipsum, or 
lipsum as it is 
sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web 
designs. The passage 
is attributed to an unknown} \hfill {}

\end{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

I've got the following outcome.[image: My Result]

Can anyone please help me with how can I get the expected outcome and align the middle column perfectly with the bullets?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] starting with `\documentclass` and all the packages necessary to compile it.

Comment: off-topic: don't use two letter font commands like `\bf` https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, the code is compilable now.

Comment: The code does not compile. `Misplaced \noalign. \hline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the geometry package would be simple for writing a CV. The following code will be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\leftcolwidth
\setlength\leftcolwidth{3cm}
\newlength\leftcolsep
\setlength\leftcolsep{5mm}

\usepackage
[left=\dimexpr\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep+3.5cm\relax,right=3.5cm]
{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pagerule
{%
   \par
   \smallskip
   \noindent
   \kern-\leftcolwidth
   \kern-\leftcolsep
   \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep}{.4pt}%
   \par
   \smallskip
   \@doendpe % suppress indent of the next line if no blank line is following
}

\newcommand*\entry[3]
{%
   \par
   \noindent
   \llap{\makebox[\leftcolwidth][l]{#1}\kern\leftcolsep}%
   \textbf{#2}%
   \hfill
   \makebox{#3}%
   \par
   \medskip % vertical space below the entries
   \@afterindentfalse % don't indent the first paragraph
   \@afterheading     % don't allow page breaks
 }

 % change the formatting of paragraph
 \renewcommand\paragraph
 {%a
   \@startsection
   {paragraph}{4}%
   {-\dimexpr\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep\relax}% move it into the margin
   {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}% vertical space before the heading
   {1em}% add a bit of vertical space after the heading
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% set the wanted font
 }
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}

 \pagerule

 \paragraph{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} 
 \entry{Sep 2020 -- Present}{Project Manager, X Consultancy}{Groningen}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item
    Have gone through certain projects. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is
    sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web
    designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown
 \end{itemize}
 \end{document}`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A sketch using packages `tabularx` and `booktabs`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}}\\
\midrule
Sep 2020 — Present & \textbf{Project Manager, X Consultancy} Groningen\\
 & %
\begin{itemize}
\item Have gone through certain projects. Lorem ipsum, or 
lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown.
\end{itemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]